# Angularjs button query

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi guys I am new to Angular JS(1.5). I have a form with two buttons, btn1 and btn2. I also have two text fields.

How can I make sure that btn2 should work only when both text fields have data in them.

Kindly help me out.

I am using this code,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" ng-disabled="queryExecuting || !canExecuteQuery()"   ng-click="executeQuery()">
<span class="zmdi zmdi-play"></span> BTN1 </button>
<input type="text" name="dbname" ng-model="dbname" required  placeholder="dbname"/>
<input type="text" name="tname" ng-model="tname" required placeholder="tname"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" ng-disabled="queryExecuting || !canExecuteQuery()" ng-click="saveToGDPQuery(dbname,tname)"> 
<span class="zmdi zmdi-play"></span> BTN2 </button>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code samples of how you are binding the text fields and the buttons to the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You could do below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" ng-disabled="!dbname || !tname" ng-click="saveToGDPQuery(dbname,tname)">
```

If you have those fields within a form you could also potentially use $error.required flags.

And by the way, you should have a "dot" in your model.